# Python beautiful soup AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all text from all options element. here is html

```
y = soup.find('div',{'class':'options push-select push-image push-checkbox push-radio'})
print(y)
<div class="options push-select push-image push-checkbox push-radio"><h3>Available Options</h3> <br/><div class="option option-select" id="option-2713"> <span class="required">*</span> <b>Size:</b><br/> <select name="option[2713]"><option value=""> --- Please Select ---</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16844">85CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16845">90CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16846">95CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16847">100CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16848">105CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16849">110CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16850">115CM</option><option data-image="https://www.pursemall.ru/image/cache/no_image-30x30h.jpg" value="16851">120CM</option> </select></div> <br/></div>
```

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
for i in y:
    i = i.find_all('option')
    print(i)
>>>[]
```

my expected result will be:

```
85CM,90CM,95CM.....
```

Comment: Your question title states you are getting an error, but your code posted is showing you are getting some result (albeit one you don't want). Could you please clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens

`y` ist not a `list` cause `find()` return type will be `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.

Whereas `find_all()` returns all the matches from document and return type will be `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` - See also [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

#### Solution

So you should iterate over `y.find_all('option')`:

```
for i in y.find_all('option'):
    print(i.text)
```

#### Output

```
 --- Please Select ---
85CM
90CM
95CM
100CM
105CM
110CM
115CM
120CM
```

#### Additiv info

To avoid the default option you can slice the result:

```
y.find_all('option')[1:]
```

or to genrate a list with text values:

```
[x.text for x in y.find_all('option')[1:]]
```

Comment: can you please explain why y isn't an list? how  do you know?

Comment: added the info to my answer, but see also [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)